# Symfony problems to align my form with fields

Tags: php, css, symfony, row, line

I've my twig with form here :

```
{{form_start(form, {'class': 'form-row align-items-center'})}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">

            {{form_row(form.typeConge, {'attr': {'onchange': 'choiceTypeConge(this)', 'class': 'form-inline'}})}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">

            {{form_row(form.soldeFloat)}}
            {{form_row(form.soldeTime)}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
    {{form_end(form)}}
```

But I've this :

[image]

How can I resolve the problem please ?

Comment: `form_row` really is supposed to create a **row** in your form. have you tried `form_widget` instead?

Comment: I tried to type {{form_widget(form)}} instead the last 2 form_rows, but same problem. I can't take the first form_row in a the form_widget because I've a function on theim

Comment: well, then the ultimate answer is to use form themes or just render the elements "manually"

Comment: How can I render the elements "manually" ?

Comment: with {{form_widget(form.fieldname)}} for each field

Comment: Yes it works fine ! Thanks !